# tcp/ip recieve bytes and convert to texture

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a small problem with this. I have another program / software which converts image to bytes and sends them on. So what I need to do now is catch those bytes in **Unity** and convert them back to image and set that as a texture.

I've already established the connection to the other software via **TCP/IP** system, connection is working, other software is sending data, but I've got no idea how to convert those bytes to img.

`Debug.Log("client message received as: " + clientMessage);`

is just a test so I can see that data is coming through.

Here is my code

```
 img.LoadRawTextureData(Loader);
 img.Apply();
 GameObject.Find("Plane").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = img;
```

//

```
private void ListenForIncommingRequests()
{
    try
    {           
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 35800);
        tcpListener.Start();
        Debug.Log("Server is listening");
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {
            using (connectedTcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient())
            {               
                using (NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream())
                {
                    int length;                         
                    while ((length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        var incommingData = new byte[length];
                        Array.Copy(bytes, 0, incommingData, 0, length); 
                        Loader = incommingData;
                        string clientMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(incommingData);
                        Debug.Log("client message received as: " + clientMessage);                            

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException socketException)
    {
        Debug.Log("SocketException " + socketException.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you can provide some more information: is `img.LoadRawTextureData(Loader);` or `img.Apply();` throwing an error? What tpye is `img` ? `Texture2D` ? Where do you call `img.Apply()` ?

Comment: `img.LoadRawTextureData(loader); img.Apply();` none of them throws a error. I call those both in inside of `Update()`. img is Texture2D

Comment: I think the problem is you try to load an `Image` as `Texture2D`. In Unity 5.x there was a function `Texture2D.LoadImage(bytes)`. I can not find this function in the current documentation...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the bytes into LoadRawTextureData?

```
private byte[] ListenForIncommingRequests()
{
    try
    {           
        tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 35800);
        tcpListener.Start();
        Debug.Log("Server is listening");
        Byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];
        while (true)
        {
            using (connectedTcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient())
            {               
                using (NetworkStream stream = connectedTcpClient.GetStream())
                {
                    int length;                         
                    while ((length = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        var incommingData = new byte[length];
                        Array.Copy(bytes, 0, incommingData, 0, length); 
                        Loader = incommingData;
                        string clientMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(incommingData);
                        Debug.Log("client message received as: " + clientMessage);                            

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SocketException socketException)
    {
        Debug.Log("SocketException " + socketException.ToString());
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

And call it like this.

```
var result = ListenForIncommingRequests();
img.LoadRawTextureData(result);
img.Apply();
GameObject.Find("Plane").GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = img;
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried to pass the bytes to LoadRawTextureData, but that didnt work. And `ListenForIncomingRequests()` is a handler for TcpClient requests, so that didn't work